# How to use textbox to search data in data grid view?

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

Here's my current code:

```
private void searchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name='{0}'", searchTextBox.Text);

    }
```

However my data grid table filters everything and becomes blank whenever I type something into the textbox. Any idea why? Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you sure that event is fired?

Comment: If you create a BindingSource to bind your DataTable to the DataGridView, you may use the "Filter" property of the BindingSource to filter the DGV without updating the  DataSource(s) each time the filter condition changes.

Comment: Please follow this stackoverflow answer [https://stackoverflow.com/a/54261346/4358971](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54261346/4358971)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The *likely* reason you are seeing a blank `DataGridView` is due to your filter string searching for exact matches to the `TextBox` text.

> ```
> "Name='{0}'"
> ```

Because you are updating this filter in the `TextBox.TextChanged` event, the first time you enter a character - no matches are found. For example, given the following grid:

```
╔════╦══════╗                    ╔════════╗
║ ID ║ Name ║      searchTextBox ║        ║
╠════╬══════╣                    ╚════════╝
║ 1  ║ Foo  ║
║ 2  ║ Bar  ║
║ 3  ║ Baz  ║
╚════╩══════╝
```

Entering `Bar` will give the following results:

```
╔════╦══════╗                    ╔════════╗
║ ID ║ Name ║      searchTextBox ║ B      ║
╠════╬══════╣                    ╚════════╝
╚════╩══════╝
╔════╦══════╗                    ╔════════╗
║ ID ║ Name ║      searchTextBox ║ Ba     ║
╠════╬══════╣                    ╚════════╝
╚════╩══════╝
╔════╦══════╗                    ╔════════╗
║ ID ║ Name ║      searchTextBox ║ Bar    ║
╠════╬══════╣                    ╚════════╝
║ 2  ║ Bar  ║
╚════╩══════╝
```

If this is the case, I've provided a few options below. If this is not the case, then you have a mystery.

---

1. **Exact matches:** consider using
   the following event handler instead so that the filter is only
   applied once you've entered the full search text:

   ```
   private void searchTextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTextBox.Text))
       {
           (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Empty;
       }
       else
       {
           (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name='{0}'", searchTextBox.Text);
       }
   }
   ```
2. **StartsWith matches:** for more fluid filtering on text changes:

   ```
   private void searchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '{0}%'", searchTextBox.Text);
   }
   ```
3. **Contains matches:** again, fluid filtering:

   ```
   private void searchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       (dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%'", searchTextBox.Text);
   }
   ```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much! It works now. Do you mind me asking another question? How do you refresh data in the datagridview?  Neither datagridview1.refresh(); nor datagridview1.update(); works for me

Comment: If you are using exact matching and you mean refreshing your data after emptying the search box: see the edit to my answer. If you have something else in mind, it may require more information and possibly posting a separate question if it's a significant amount of info.

Comment: I used 3th method but the compiler always show up error `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`. What causes this?

Comment: @TravisSu That is a [`NullReferenceException`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4660186/3773066).  One of the objects you are accessing is likely not initialized.

Comment: @OhBeWise do I need to initialized `DataTable` and `DefaultView` ?

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a new query against the database in which you populated the grid?

Use the textbox text with LIKE

Edit:

If you want the grid to update with the search, use AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

OhBeWise answer is the best but until i add something to get points i'm not allowed to like it.

so i'll add this,
 remember in OhBeWise's answer that your filtering the rows to be listed but using the column name from the query. the query used to set the datasource of the datagridview.

For Instance in my example "LoginID" is in the select statement.

```
(dataGridViewTheToGrid.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("LoginID LIKE '{0}%'", textBoxFindUserID.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition if you want a multi-column search use this code

```
(dataGridView1.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Name LIKE '%{0}%' OR ID LIKE '%{0}%'", searchTextBox.Text);
```