# How to filter the information in the datagridview datasource?

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataview

First of all, I am sorry for my question, I know it's very common, I've read [How to use textbox to search data in data grid view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31809201/how-to-use-textbox-to-search-data-in-data-grid-view) without succes

I'm new into C# and this is the first time I give it a shot!

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (tableDataGridView.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("Id LIKE '%{0}%'",
                                                    "Merk LIKE '%{0}%'",
                                                    "Model LIKE '%{0}%'",
                                                    "Bouwjaar LIKE '%{0}%'",
                                                    "Problemen LIKE '%{0}%'", textBox1.Text);
    }
```

Comment: I think you need to combine all your `column LIKE` arguments into 1 string, then have `textBox1.Text` as the second argument. `String.Format()` expects the first argument to have "the complete string", so to speak, followed by all the values to replace `{n}` with. So basically `Id LIKE '%{0}%' OR Merk LIKE ...`

Comment: As said in the comment above this is not how string.Format is expected to be used (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format(v=vs.110).aspx). In any case, in the future you should focus on one problem at the time. For example: if you don't know how to use RowFilter and String.Format, better don't try both of them at the same time.

Comment: You've got the filtering concept down. Just take sab669's advice on  `string.Format("Id LIKE '%{0}%' OR Merk LIKE '%{0}%' OR...", textBox1.Text);`

Comment: do you resolve your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter rows in datagrid I use a dataview, my datagrid itemsource is set with a datatable like this:

```
myDatagrid.ItemSource = myDataTable.defaultview; \\all rows are visible
```

I set a string for the filtering, you can use string.format:

```
 string strFilter = String.Format("columName1 LIKE {0} AND columnName2 < {1}", var1,var2); \\use LIKE to find equality between string values but you can also compare DateTime... like I do it in my sample with columnName2
```

and set a dataview to filter your datagrid

```
 DataView dv = new DataView(myDataTable, strFilter, "columnName2 DESC", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
```

parameter 1: the ItemSource of your datagrid myDataTable
2 : your filter string
3 : you can ordering rows resulting
4:  represent the rows on which you apply the filter

finally you need to refresh your datagrid with your new dataview

```
myDataGrid.ItemSource = dv;
```

Comment: Glad I could help you