# Search values from textBox (located in Form2) in dataGrid (located in Form1)

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, winforms, datagrid

I want to search a value from searchTBoxW (SearchWindow.cs) in dGVPlan (dataGrid, located in frPlanMain.cs).
The dataGrid in frPlanMain.cs loads the .xls file by entering in locTBox the path of the file, i do not use SQL for this.
I have tried several ways to do this but they dont seem to work, i am new to Visual Studio and C#.

The code for frPlanMain.cs (Form1):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace Plan_de_lucru_1._0
{
    public partial class frPlanMain : Form
    {

        public frPlanMain()
        {
            public SearchWindow frm2;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void frPlanMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void GoButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constr = "Provider = MicroSoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + locTBox.Text + "; Extended Properties =\"Excel 8.0; HDR=Yes;\";";
            OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
            OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * From [" + shTBox.Text + "$]", con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dt);
            dGVPlan.DataSource = dt;
            new SearchWindow().Show();
            this.Show();
        }
    }
}
```

The code for SearchWindow.cs (Form2):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Plan_de_lucru_1._0
{
    public partial class SearchWindow : Form
    {
        public frPlanMain refTofrPlanMain;

        public SearchWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void SearchButtonW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
        bs.DataSource = refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.DataSource;
        bs.Filter = " like '%" + searchTBoxW.Text + "%'";
        refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.DataSource = bs;
        }

    }
}
```

I have asked this similar question in another post but i could not adapt the code or understand why it did not work : [Search value in textBox so it finds it in the data located in gridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36221171/search-value-in-textbox-so-it-finds-it-in-the-data-located-in-gridview/36221465#36221465)

Thank you very much for the interest and help provided and i am sorry if i ask too much.

Comment: Your search window doesn't do anything at all. Is it a window where you type in the search key a result window or both?

Comment: Yes, it is missing the code, i tryed several examples and they threw me errors even if i referenced corectly to the items needed. I am trying to enter a value in searchTBox ( a textbox ) and search it in my DataGridView by pressing the SearchButtonW.

Comment: I updated Form2 with the command that i used and i get An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could attach an event handler to searhc form:

```
public partial class SearchWindow : Form
{
    public String SearchKey{
       get{return searchKey_textbox.Text}
    }
    public SearchWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SearchButtonW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public void searchBtn_attachClickHandler(EventHandler eh){
         searchBtn.Click += eh;
    }

}
```

Next instead of `new SearchWindow().Show();` use following code:

```
String searchKey = "";  //This variable could be global (just so you could use the next few lines almost anywhere
SearchWindow sw = new SearchWindow(); //create a form and attach a handler that will be triggered when "search" button in search form is clicked
//Note that you only need to attach the handler (below) only when you create the form.
sw.searchBtn_attachClickHandler += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
searchKey = sw.SearchKey;
sw.close //will close after getting the search key, remove this line if you don't want it
};
sw.Show(); //finally shows the form
//at this point your searchKey form should already have the value from your search form.
```

Note that you might have to rename some variables, I'm writing this without knowing your names.

**EDIT: Second option based on your edit of search form**
This is actually important, because it's a valid method to do it, but you're missing a parameter in constructor.

```
public partial class SearchWindow : Form
{
    public frPlanMain refTofrPlanMain;

    public SearchWindow(frPlanMain f) //<<Edit made here 
    {
        refTofrPlanMain = f;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SearchButtonW_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    bs.DataSource = refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.DataSource;
    bs.Filter = "[column name] like '%" + searchTBoxW.Text + "%'";
    refTofrPlanMain.dGVPlan.DataSource = bs;
    }

}
```

Instead of `new SearchWindow().Show();` use `new SearchWindow(this).Show();`

Long story short this second part of answer passes your main form as an argument, so that changes could be made to data in it. You kept all the logic, but didn't pass the form.

Comment: I recive the following error: Additional information: Syntax error: Missing operand before 'Like' operator. Is it because i do not referance to a certain column ? I belive something is missing in  bs.Filter = " like '%" + searchTBoxW.Text + "%'"; before like.

Comment: oh, right, you are supposed to specifify the column and that portion of a string. Didn't check the code.

Comment: Problem is that i import a .xls from a certain path and do not have predetermined columns. Or is it possible to create a column and tell the GridView what columns to show from the .xls file ?

Comment: You could use [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b88a501d-c603-4955-8e4c-b718aa56b156/importing-rowname-and-columnname-from-an-excelfile-to-a-datagridview-?forum=winformsdatacontrols) on MS website to create DataGridView to read column names (from first row of the xls) manually. The answer is pretty straightforward, create columns from names in first row of .xls file, then add all the rows.

Comment: Thank you. Almost got it, still have to work on how to define the column from where to get the text but it worked on how to assign columns. Could i contact you if i have a quesiton reltated to this ?

Comment: You can try, but generally speaking, I check stack exchange like once a month or so. In other words, chances are you might have to wait long for a reply.