# Changing the Table data in a datagridview empties the table instead of repopulating

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have sucessfully populated a datagrid view from a list. The problem lies with trying to change the data source after a search has been initiated.

I'm sucessfully returning intended results from the below code.

```
        int ResultIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < Members.Count; i++)
        {
            if (Members[i].ToonName == ToonSearchName.Text)
            {
                ResultIndex = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        var Source = new BindingSource();


        MessageBox.Show(ResultIndex.ToString()); // Returns the correct Index
        MessageBox.Show(Members[ResultIndex].ID); // Returns the correct value

        MemberListView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
        MemberListView.Columns.Clear();
        MemberListView.DataSource = this.Members[ResultIndex]; // Datagrid view turns blank after this line
```

The actual list is as followed:

```
     public class DVMemberlist
        {

            public string ID { get; set; }
            public string ToonName { get; set; }
            public string AddedOn { get; set; }
            public string AddedBy { get; set; }
            public string Enteries { get; set; }


        }
```

It seems even know i'm able to print expected data into the message box, when trying to change the data source for the datagridview it empties and is blank rather showing 1 row.

First picture is the populated data when the form is loaded. Which is exactly as intended.

[image: Correctly populated data]

The second image is after the search has been performed for "Ocz7ok3MqH"   which message boxes show the intended ID and the intended index. But the datagridview is returned blank

[image: Unintended Results]

Comment: You clear the columns and use an entirely different datasource, one which doesnt even appear to be a collection.  There is a wonderful property called `RowFilter` for a proper `DataGridView` filter and even a `DataView` for more extensive operations

Comment: Nyssa was spot on. My [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31818204/3773066) on `RowFilter` behavior might help.