# how to data dynamic search in C# and search is perform using textbox key event

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 1 text box and 1 grid i want to search dynamic data using Text box using key press event and highlight that word in grid that I want to search.

Comment: Duplicate of here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163616/gridview-filtering-using-textbox-in-asp-net

Comment: Your question is probably answered some where else. Please look at the other questions and search the web before posting a question.

Answer (score 0):

Attach an **OnKeyPress** event to your TextBox and write your logic in that event.

```
private void TextBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)        
{
    string value = TextBox.Text;
    foreach(GridViewRow row in GridView.Rows)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < GridView.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            string cellText = row.Cells[i].Text;
            if(cellText == value)
            {
                // Highlights the entire row
                row.DefaultCellStyle.SelectionBackColor = Color.Yellow;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```